# javascript: How to show a message using an alert after Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display an alert after an Ajax request has been submited successfully.

```
$.post(
    "ajax_request.php", {
      email: email
    },
    function(data) {
      $('#message').html(data);
      var y = $('#message').text();
      if (y == 'exists') {
        alert('text');
    }
);
```

The script above works, but I cannot display the alert, although the **var y** contains the word exists.

Comment: `==` does not mean "contains"

Comment: do console,log(y); check what exactly it showing

Comment: Means its not going in `if`. Check console for errors

Comment: You are checking if `y` is exactly `"exists"`, which is not what you want to do as i read out of your question. If you want to check if `y` contains the `"exists"` you have to use `y.indexOf("exists")`.

Comment: You don't need to request the DOM, and your question seems to mean than you want exact string match. I guess there is some extra white space(s) in string, so try: `if(data.trim() === "exists")`. Now a better way would be to return JSON from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to check if one string contains another, use the following code:

```
if (y.indexOf('exists') > -1) {
    alert('test');
}
```

**Reading Material**

[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
if(y.indexOf('exists') != -1){
  alert('text');                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

== is used for comparing if two variables are equal or not. It doesn't check data type.

=== is used for comparing two variables if they are equal as well as their data type is same.

In your case, you don't have to use any of them because you need to check whether a string contains a substring or not.

To check whether a string contains a particular substring or not, you need to use indexOf().

Now, Assuming that you are getting some data as the response and somehow storing it in variable y.

Now, to check whether y contains word 'exists' or not, you should check it the following way.

```
if(y.indexOf('exists) != -1) {
    //do something
}
```

Let's define y and check

```
 var y = "Does this sentence contain word exist?";
    y.indexOf('exist');

Output : 32
```

If y doesn't contain exist, then the output would have been 1.